# Binding / relating properties of two ViewModels to each other

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I directly start with a picture, showing the structure that I have, so that I can ask my question using the picture.

[image: relation between the ViewModels]

I have a `ParentModel` like this:

```
Public Class ParentModel
    public Property ModelValue_A As String
    Public Property ModelValue_B As String
End Class
```

I have a `ParentViewModel`, which has two properties of type `ChildViewModel`.

```
Public Class ParentViewModel
    Public Property Parent As ParentModel
    Public Property ChildViewModel_A As ChildViewModel
    Public Property ChildViewModel_B As ChildViewModel

    Sub New
        ChildViewModel_A = New ChildViewModel()
        ChildViewModel_B = New ChildViewModel()
    End Sub
End Class
```

My `ParentView` is like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ChildViewModel_A}"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ChildViewModel_B}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

My `ChildViewModel` is like this:

```
Public Class ChildViewModel
    Private _ChildValue As String

    Public Property ChildValue As String
        Get
            Return _ChildValue
        End Get
        Set
            _ChildValue = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged(NameOf(ChildValue))
        End Set
End Class
```

My `ChildView` is like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ChildValue}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

My `NotifyPropertyChanged` method:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Protected Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(info As [String])
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub
```

When I start the application, I get a view similar to the picture above. There, I can change the `ChildValue` by typing in the `TextBox` of `ChildView`. However, I still don't have a connection / relationship between each `ChildValue` to its corresponding property of `ParentViewModel`: `ChildViewModel_A` and `ChildViewModel_B`.

**My question is**: How can I change `ModelValue_A` by changing `ChildValue` of `ChildViewModel_A`, and respectively, change `ModelValue_B` by changing `ChildValue` of `ChildViewModel_B`?

Comment: The ParentViewModel can subscribe to the 2 NotifyPropChanged events. You will have to code for the split PropA / PropB somewhere.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do you mean by "subscribe to the 2 NotifyPropChanged events."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook up an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ChildViewModel`(s) in your `ParentViewModel` class and set the properties of the `ParentModel` in this one:

```
Public Class ParentViewModel
    Public Property Parent As ParentModel
    Public Property ChildViewModel_A As ChildViewModel
    Public Property ChildViewModel_B As ChildViewModel

    Sub New()
        ChildViewModel_A = New ChildViewModel()
        ChildViewModel_B = New ChildViewModel()

        AddHandler ChildViewModel_A.PropertyChanged, AddressOf OnPropertyChangedA
        AddHandler ChildViewModel_B.PropertyChanged, AddressOf OnPropertyChangedB

    End Sub

    Private Sub OnPropertyChangedA(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Parent.ModelValue_A = ChildViewModel_A.ChildValue
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnPropertyChangedB(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        Parent.ModelValue_B = ChildViewModel_B.ChildValue
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your solution, but `OnPropertyChangedA` and `OnPropertyChangedB` don't get called. Do I need to Implement the `PropertyChanged` event in a special way?

Comment: The `ChildViewModel` class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications. You haven't posted your `NotifyPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: yeah you are right. All classes actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I added my `NotifyPropertyChanged` method to the question.

Comment: @Yvonnila: How do you know that the event handlers don't get called? Did you try to put breakpoints in the methods? It works just fine for me so you are obviously doing something wrong or not giving the full picture.

Comment: Yes, I put a breakpoint in the methods and changed both `ChildValue`s. The setter of the corresponding `ChildValue`s are called, but not the eventhandlers.

Comment: Then o are probably creating several instance of the `ChildViewModel` class. Put a breakpoint in the constructor to find out. Like I said, it works for me.

Comment: @mm yes of course I am creating several instances of the `ChildViewModel`. Each `ParentViewModel` contains 2 instances of `ChildViewModel`: `ChildViewModel_A` and `ChildViewModel_B`

Comment: Thank you anyway for your reply

Comment: Yes, there should be only two instances created in total.